# problem extracting zip file

Tags: zip

After I unzipped/extracted a zip file this message shows:

```
Archive:  /home/manager/Desktop/ebirforms_package_v6.1 (2)/Offline eBIRForms Package v6.1 setup.exe
[/home/manager/Desktop/ebirforms_package_v6.1 (2)/Offline eBIRForms Package v6.1 setup.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/manager/Desktop/ebirforms_package_v6.1 (2)/Offline eBIRForms Package v6.1 setup.exe or
          /home/manager/Desktop/ebirforms_package_v6.1 (2)/Offline eBIRForms Package v6.1 setup.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/manager/Desktop/ebirforms_package_v6.1 (2)/Offline eBIRForms Package v6.1 setup.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: You are making a factual statement. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your only have the first part of a two-part `Offline eBIRForms Package v6.1 setup.exe` archive in your working directory. The error message is telling you that you need to download part 2 of the same archive to your working directory, so that you will be able to extract all of the files from that two-part archive.